# Adapt obfuscated javascript (positioning a nice canvas animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, positioning

On Codepen I found a neat little interactive graphic use of Javascript, jQuery, and the canvas element.

http://codepen.io/altescape/pen/tbdao

> Note: After reading the comments below, I removed the demo I had
>   uploaded, and even the author of the pen acknowledges he 'just wanted
>   to play' with it and didn't create it. Hence, I am linking to it just
>   because it's neat but using it without permission is a no-no. Thanks
>   for bringing it to my attention.

What I want is to insert it on that (my) site's homepage, in the place of the "under construction message" that is front and center. I'm pretty new to JS but I am good with HTML & CSS, and aware of the basics of DOM...I thought I'd be able to figure out how to adjust it appropriately but no luck, when I inserted the code as if it were HTML going in a div it just floated in the middle of the screen like it is now.

About 90% to the bottom of the [JS file](http://adaminfinitum.com/js/dazzlecms_1.js) there are a few lines of code:

```
$(function () {
function n(d) {
    var b = "";
    for (jj = 0; jj < d.length; jj++) b += d.charCodeAt(jj).toString(16);
    return b
}
function p() {
    j.attr({
        height: $(window).height(),
        width: $(window).width()
    });
    k = j.width();
    l = j.height();
    q()
}
```

The whole height and width seemed promising but making and adjustment broke it entirely. Can anybody explain to me how to make sense of or successfully manipulate this code so I can position it...perhaps even in a way that will allow it to display appropriately in different size browser windows (I am using CSS media queries)?

I read every post on here that seemed to be related, but to be honest, I might not even be using relevant query phrases as I am not sure if I am using the right terminology. I am completely lost on this one and a bit out of my league, thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to alter, but the position of "hello" changes if you modify the `180` at the very bottom of the file (for `curPos` and `originalPos`).

Comment: You really should link to the Codepen page where you found that script. And if it is as obfuscated as this, are you sure you are allowed to use it at all?

Comment: You do realize this code originates with http://dazzlecms.com? Which [has a blog](http://blog.dazzlecms.com/)?

Comment: I did realize it was from dazzle cms but (I viewed the original there)but no I didn't know they had a blog (or see any navigation or anything). I'll look into it...and I didn't even know it was obfuscated, I was guessing all the numbers were coordinates for each of the dots but I couldn't really make heads or tails of it. -Thanks